# Php upload --- doesnt upload to specified path

Tags: php

i have a problem with uploading.

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("noktamedya.com/CVs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "noktamedya.com/CVs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "noktamedya.com/CVs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

doesnt upload why :( i set my path where to upload but i always face 404 error because doesnt upload to specified path

i also set my directory to 777 in order to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the domain name when uploading file. PHP doesn't care.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "/CVs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use destination path as absolute path.
Smthing like that:

```
//....
$destPath = '/usr/www/noktamedya.com/CVs/';
if (is_dir($destPath))
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          $destPath . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . $destPath . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
          }
}
else
{
    echo $destPath . 'path doesn't exist';
    die();
}

//....
```

Comment: omg thank you . Just one more question . How can i upload docx's ? $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword" is it true?

Comment: "application/msword" is for MS Word .doc files (BIFF format). For the more recent MS Word 2007+ .docx files, you need "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

Comment: Here you can find any mimetype you are searching for: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html. So your mime type looks correct.